# Flexicious Ultimate Datagrid: set height of column header

Tags: flex-datagrid, flexicious

I am adding a headerRenderer to the FlexDataGridColumn. Is it possible to customize the height of the FlexDataGridColumn so that all elements of the headerRenderer are visible ?

Comment: Which version are you on? The latest version has `variableHeaderHeight` property that should do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexicious 2.9 has variableHeaderHeight property that should do this.

Comment: I am using the Trial Flex 4 Ultimate Grid. There are only variableRowHeight and variableRowHeightUseRendererForCalculation. I manage it using headerRowHeight. Thanks